# How to change HTML content based on URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, single-page-application

I have a HTML page where I have two IFrames, and there are two buttons controlling which of them is visible.

Here is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyPage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="leftbar">
        <button id="btn_1" class="leftbar-button" onclick="openTab(event, 'sec1')">Section1</button>
        <button id="btn_2" class="leftbar-button" onclick="openTab(event, 'sec2')">Section2</button>
    </div>

    <div id="sec1" class="tabcontent">
      <iframe src="section1.html"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="sec2" class="tabcontent">
      <iframe src="section2.html"></iframe>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div id="clear" class="clear" style="clear: both; height: 0;"></div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `main.js`:

```
function onSwInit()
{
    // Set the home page to be displayed
    document.getElementById("sec1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("btn_1").className += " active";
}

function openTab(evt, tabName)
{
  // Hide all content
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++)
  {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Display the clicked section
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("leftbar-button");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++)
  {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Now, as one can see, by default, the page begins with btn_1 active and the corresponding IFrame `section1.html` visible. Now the problem is, suppose I want to share the URL of the page with the IFrame `section2.html` visible, how do I do it?

I am fine with a HTML, Javascript or PHP solution.

Comment: You can add parameters at the end of a url that can be accessed in the code. Here is documentation on how to get these parameters in php: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: As an aside, don't concatenate classnames like you're doing with `getElementById("btn_1").className += " active";` use the `element.classList` instead. If you have `var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn_1")` you can add and remove classes with `btn1.classList.add('active')` and `btn1.classList.remove('active')`

Comment: @Logiwan992 Thanks! That would be a good solution. Perhaps you could write it as an answer?

Comment: @StephenP That is a good hint. Looks much more elegant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript:

1. Avoid using inline on* handlers (onclick, oninput, etc) and use event listeners within your JavaScript itself. Remove the `onclick` handlers and use `querySelectorAll` to retrieve all the buttons and assign them to a variable, say `btns`.
2. Use `forEach()` to add a `click` event listener to each button in your `btns` variable that will load a function called say, `toggleFrames()`.
3. Inside that function, retrieve all the elements with class name `tabcontent` using `querySelectorAll` again and assign them to a variable, say `frames`.
4. Use `subtr()` to retrieve the `number` from your button id e.g. the `2` in `btn_2` which you will use to compare with the ids of each tab content in the variable `frames`.
5. Use `forEach()` on the variable `frames` and check if the number in the id of the clicked button matches the number in the id of each tabcontent e.g. the `2` in `sec2` and if they do, add the `active` class name and change the css `display` property of that element to `block`.
6. Use `window.location.href` to retrieve the current page url and then use the [search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method to check if the url string contains the id of one of your iframes. If there is a match, display that iframe and hide the other iframe.

---

Check and run the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the above:

```js
//Check URL

function checkUrl() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var frames = document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent');
  frames.forEach(frame => {
    if( url.search( frame.id ) > 0 ) {
      frame.style.display = "block";
      frame.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      frame.style.display = "none";
      frame.classList.remove("active");
    }
  })
}

window.onload = checkUrl();

//Check Button Click

var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".leftbar-button");

function toggleFrame(e){
  var frames = document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent');
 var x = e.target.id.substr(-1);
  frames.forEach(frame => {
   if(frame.id.includes(x)){
     frame.style.display = "block";
        frame.classList.add("active");
    } else {
     frame.style.display = "none";
        frame.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
  
}

btns.forEach(btn => {
 btn.addEventListener("click", toggleFrame);
})
```

```css
.tabcontent {padding:20px 10px;text-align:center;background-color: #000;color:#FFF;}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
    <div class="leftbar">
        <button id="btn_1" class="leftbar-button">Section1</button>
        <button id="btn_2" class="leftbar-button">Section2</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="sec1" class="tabcontent">
      <h1>
      Iframe 1 here
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="sec2" class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
      <h1>
      Iframe 2 here
      </h1>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve my problem per se, but is a very useful idea. Can you tell me why using event listeners is better than handlers (I mean generally)?

Comment: @mahesh As mentioned by @Alnitak [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice#5871775), one of the reasons why you should avoid using inline handlers is because it mixes your **code**(here, *JavaScript*) and your **markup**(here, *HTML*) which is generally something we should avoid. Another reason to not use handlers is that the handlers end up going through `eval()` and running in the global scope.

Comment: `Event listeners` however, not only avoid the above problems but they also allow us to bind multiple functions to a single event which is not possible with handlers regardless of whether they are inline or not.

Comment: Check out the other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) for other reasons why using inline handlers and/or non-inline handlers in general is a bad practice.

Comment: @mahesh I have edited the code. Check **Point 6** as well as the first few lines of the code snippet to see how you can display the iframe based on your url.

Comment: Now whenever you try to access say `www.yourWebsite.com/somePage/#sec2` or `www.yourWebsite.coma/somePage?sec2`, the iframe `sec2` will be displayed by default.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP:

You can't; that's the whole point of a single page application (SPA). If you want to be able to share individual iframes, you'll need to navigate to `section2.html` directly. Naturally, that won't have any of the surrounding content.

If you want that surrounding content (to be visible on each page), you'd be better off making use of **[HTML Imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)**, **[`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**, or better yet, **[PHP includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)**:

Page 1:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<!-- iframe content -->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<!-- iframe content -->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyPage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="leftbar">
        <button id="btn_1" class="leftbar-button" onclick="openTab(event, 'sec1')">Section1</button>
        <button id="btn_2" class="leftbar-button" onclick="openTab(event, 'sec2')">Section2</button>
    </div>
```

footer.php:

```
  <div id="clear" class="clear" style="clear: both; height: 0;"></div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is one way to solve it, but that would still mean I have then two pages, which is what I am trying to avoid.